# Passing data to a function with an unknown number of programmatically defined variables in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Let's assume I have the following code:

```
x = data.table(rowid=1:10, N1=2:11, N2=3:12, N3=4:13)
x[, sum(c(N1, N2, N3)),by=rowid]
```

Now assume I don't know the column names N1, N2, N3 in advance and they are saved in the vector `colnames=c("N1", "N2", "N3")`. If I know the number of variables to pass to `sum()`, I can plug in `colnames` as follows:

```
x[, sum(c(get(colnames[1]),get(colnames[2]),get(colnames[3]))),by=rowid]
```

Now assume I don't know the length of `colnames`. Is there any way I can rewrite the above so it works? Something like `x[, sum(c(sapply(colnames, as.name))),by=rowid]` (note this exact expression doesn't work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sums all columns except `rowid` :

```
x[, sum(.SD), by = rowid]
```

This sums only those columns named in character vector `colnames` :

```
x[, sum(.SD), by = rowid, .SDcols = colnames]
```

In both cases the sums are by `rowid` .